# Removing set of characters from the end of the string

Tags: python, string, replace, object-slicing

I want to remove @email.com from this string and also as such that even if the "myemail" part is changed the code should still work
I did this:

```
email = "myemail@email.com"
a = a.replace(a[-10:-1],'')
print(a)
```

Output:

```
myemailm
```

I wanted to remove that 'm' as well but i can't find a way to do so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean: `a = a.replace(a[-10:],'')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your slice is specifically excluding the last character.  You're also making things more complicated than they need to be by using both a slice and a replace; any one of these on its own will do the job more simply:

```
>>> "myemail@email.com"[:-10]
'myemail'
>>> "myemail@email.com".replace("@email.com", "")
'myemail'
>>> "myemail@email.com".split("@")[0]
'myemail'
```

Comment: oh thank you gotta revise string slicing i completely forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

Find the index of `@` and keep the first part

```
email = "myemail@email.com"
email = email[:email.index('@')]
print(email)
```

Output:

```
myemail
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below:

```
email = "myemail@email.com"
a = email.split('@')
a[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can make it with a split.

```
In [1]: "myemail@email.com".split("@")[0]                                                                                                     
Out[1]: 'myemail'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
email = "myemail@email.com"
a = email.split("@")[0]
print(a)
```

gives output:

```
myemail
```

`email.split("a")` returns a list `["myemail", "email.com"]` from which you can take the first element using `[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You could split the email into a list, using the @ as a separator, then print the first item in the list, which would be everything before the @. This would account for domain names of different length. For example, @yahoo.com is longer than @gmail.com, you'd have to account for the individual lengths.

```
email = "myemail@email.com"
a = email.split("@")[0]
print(a)
```

Or you can use the replace method as you are and do it on a case by case basis, but your splice is incorrect. The stop value is not included. So by your saying `a = a.replace(a[-10:-1] , '')` you haven't replaced the m from .com. If you were to instead say `a = a.replace(a[-10:],'')` you will replace everything from the -10th index to the end of the string.

Another potential solution would be to find the index of the @.

```
a = email[0:email.index('@')]
```

Answer (score 0):

code:

email = "myemail@email.com"

new_email = email.replace(email[-10:],'')

print(new_email)

output:
myemail

Comment: Hi Labhesh, code statements in your answer should be in proper format and properly drafted.